# Best way to program for Windows application tests

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation

I'm currently facing an issue. I had to manage an automatisation of tests to perform UI testing of a Windows application. I do not have the source code just the binary.

I have tried pywinauto but I'm not sure to find the best way to catch message. If I expect yes or no as answer of a question for example.

I need a tool easy to use and who is able to click, find a field, recognize a string or make snapshot.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If ease of use is the goal, you might take a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). In my experience it's not only easy to get started with, but also quite reliable.